# Django -- foreign key doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models in my Django app:

```py
class Dataset(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Imagefile(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36, default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=image_directory_path)
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(
        Dataset,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="imagefiles",
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

class Annotation(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=image_annotation_directory_path)
    json = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    imagefile = models.ForeignKey(
        Imagefile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="annotation",
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
```

What I want to achieve is to store one `Dataset` that has multiple `Imagefiles`, and each `Imagefile` can have either 0 or 1 related `Annotation`.

I am able to create a `Dataset` and `Imagefiles` that belong to it. When I try to create the `Annotation`, however, it is not registered in the `Imagefile`. In other words, the `Annotation` refers to the `Imagefile`, but the `Imagefile` sees an empty `Annotation`.

This is how I create my test case:

```py
dataset = Dataset.objects.get(uuid=..., name='test_dataset')

new_imagefile = Imagefile.objects.create(
                    uuid=...,
                    dataset=dataset,
                    name='test_image.png'
                )
new_imagefile.file.save('/some/existing/path/image.png', open('test_image.png', "rb"))

new_annot = Annotation.objects.create(imagefile=new_imagefile)
new_annot.image.save('/some/other/existing/path/annot.png', open('annot.png', "rb"))
```

When the above process is done, printing `new_imagefile.annotation` results in `dataset.Annotation.None`. I've been fighting with this for several hours, any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I found the problem right after I posted my question -- in the definition of `Annotation`, I should have used `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey`. That fixed my problem.

I hope this can help other people that have the same problem.